# PySide6 Error: Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside6

I am having an issue with PySide6 library on my computer. Every time I run an application using this library, I receive a warning message. Although the application functions properly, the icons don't work. I am using Anaconda environments on my computer and installed PySide6 using the 'pip install PySide6' command on the Anaconda Prompt. Additionally, I am using Visual Studio Code to run the program, and my current Python version is 3.10.9.

I have attempted to change my environment variable to access the path directly, and I even tried downloading the incompatible DLLs. While this worked, it caused all of my Anaconda applications to stop functioning. So, I am looking for an alternative solution. I also attempted to update Anaconda, but the issue persists.

The warnings that appear when I try to load the icon are:

```
PS C:\Ingeconcreto\Programación> & C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/python.exe c:/Ingeconcreto/Programación/PySide6/MainWindow/main.py
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/platforms/qdirect2d.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/platforms/qminimal.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/platforms/qoffscreen.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/platforms/qwebgl.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/platformthemes/qxdgdesktopportal.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/styles/qwindowsvistastyle.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/iconengines/qsvgicon.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/imageformats/qgif.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/imageformats/qicns.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/imageformats/qico.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/imageformats/qjpeg.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/imageformats/qpdf.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/imageformats/qsvg.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/imageformats/qtga.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/imageformats/qtiff.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/imageformats/qwbmp.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Users/Ingeniero/anaconda3/Library/plugins/imageformats/qwebp.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
```

And the program looks like this:

[image: Aplication attempt, Blue box being the icon that doesnt appear]

The code for my window is:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QToolBar,QPushButton
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize
from PySide6.QtGui import QAction, QIcon

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__()
        self.app = app
        self.setWindowTitle("Custom Window")


        ## MenuBar and Menus
        menu_bar = self.menuBar()
        file_menu = menu_bar.addMenu("File")
        quit_action = file_menu.addAction("Quit")
        quit_action.triggered.connect(self.quit_app)

        edit_menu = menu_bar.addMenu("Edit")
        edit_menu.addAction("Copy")
        edit_menu.addAction("Cut")
        edit_menu.addAction("Paste")
        edit_menu.addAction("Undo")
        edit_menu.addAction("Redo")

        ### ToolBar
        toolbar = QToolBar("Main Toolbar")
        toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(15,10))
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)

        #Add Action to toolbar
        toolbar.addAction(quit_action)

        action1 = QAction("Alguna cosa",self)
        action1.setStatusTip("Mensaje de estatus para la accion")
        action1.triggered.connect(self.toolbar_button_click)
        toolbar.addAction(action1)

        icon = QIcon("Imagen.ico")
        icon.actualSize(QSize(5,5))
        action2 = QAction(icon,"Saludo",self)
        action2.setStatusTip("No se donde se ve esto")
        action2.triggered.connect(self.toolbar_button_click)
        # action2.setCheckable(True)
        toolbar.addAction(action2)
        
        toolbar.addSeparator()
        toolbar.addWidget(QPushButton("Otros"))



    def toolbar_button_click(self):
        print("Action1 triggered")

    def quit_app(self):
        self.app.quit()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Anaconda, but it looks like you have a previous Qt 5 version installed in the wrong path (the Anaconda root), and you also possibly installed PySide there too, which is not a good thing.

Comment: How do I reinstall the qt 5 and PySide on the correct path? And how do I know which is the correct path?